# node.js function call order, Spotify Web API

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify-app

I'm trying to use Spotify Web API with a wrapper for node.js. Before I do any of the API calls, I need to set the access token. In my script, I call the `setAccessToken` function first, and then call some API request below. However, due to the async nature of node.js my `setAccessToken` method is called after my API requests, which results in failed API requests. How can I make sure my `setAccessToken` function returns before I call API requests below (API request lines start with `spotifyApi.getMySavedTracks` call)

```
app.get('/callback', (req, res) => {
  var code = req.query.code || null;
  if (code === null) {
      console.log("code is null");
  }

  async function authorize() {
    const data = await spotifyApi.authorizationCodeGrant(code);
    // console.log('The token expires in ' + data.body['expires_in']);
    // console.log('The access token is ' + data.body['access_token']);
    // console.log('The refresh token is ' + data.body['refresh_token']);
    // Set the access token on the API object to use it in later calls
    accesToken = data.body['access_token'];
    refreshToken = data.body['refresh_token'];
    spotifyApi.setAccessToken(accesToken);
    spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(refreshToken);
  }

  try {
    authorize();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Something went wrong!', err);
  }

  spotifyApi.getMySavedTracks({
    limit : lim,
    offset: 1
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    return data.body.items;
  }, function(err) {
    console.log('Something went wrong!', err);
  })
  .then(function(items) {
    let ids = [];
    items.forEach(function(item) {
      ids.push(item.track.id);
    })
    return spotifyApi.getAudioFeaturesForTracks(ids); //2xc8WSkjAp4xRGV6I1Aktb
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    let songs = data.body.audio_features;
    //console.log(songs);
    let filteredSongURIs = [];
    songs.forEach(function(song) {
      if ((song.energy >= moodScore-offset) && (song.energy <= moodScore+offset)) {
        filteredSongURIs.push(song.uri);
      }
    })

    //Create Playlist with filtered songs
    spotifyApi.createPlaylist('Mooder Playlist', { 'description': 'My description', 'public': true })
    .then(function(data) {
      return data.body.id;
    }, function(err) {
      console.log('Something went wrong!', err);
    })
    .then(function(playlist) {
      spotifyApi.addTracksToPlaylist(playlist, filteredSongURIs)
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log('Added tracks to playlist!');
    }, function(err) {
      console.log('Something went wrong!', err);
    });
    
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });


  res.redirect('/testAPI');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap all your code after `setAccessToken` into another `then`, or you can `await` that `Promise` to end:

```js
// Add `async` here
app.get('/callback', async (req, res) => {
  var code = req.query.code || null;
  if (code === null) {
      console.log("code is null");
  }
  try {
    const data = await spotifyApi.authorizationCodeGrant(code);
    // console.log('The token expires in ' + data.body['expires_in']);
    // console.log('The access token is ' + data.body['access_token']);
    // console.log('The refresh token is ' + data.body['refresh_token']);
    // Set the access token on the API object to use it in later calls
    accesToken = data.body['access_token'];
    refreshToken = data.body['refresh_token'];
    spotifyApi.setAccessToken(accesToken);
    spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(refreshToken);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Something went wrong!', err);
  }

  // The rest of your code
```

Comment: turns out ```spotifyApi.authorizationCodeGrant``` is not a async function. Because I got "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function"   @emi

Comment: The problem is not in `spotifyApi.authorizationCodeGrant` but in the function calling it that needs to be declared as `async` in order to be allowed to use `await`.

Comment: I put all the code inside try block in an async function and called that in try. However I'm getting the same issue

Comment: @Khashhogi Sorry, I can't understand that last comment.

Comment: Update your question accordingly

Comment: That's not ok. Please, show the function that wraps everything so I can help better.

Comment: I put the whole function, thanks for your time!

Comment: What is `app.get`? I mean, what is `app`? What does `app.get` returns? What is the specification (link to docs) of `app.get`?

Comment: app is express.js API (```const app = express();```). So it doesn't return anything, it just does some API calls and then redirects the user to a different endpoint